# regarding object recycling

Tags: java

I have a question. What is wrong with regards to the below code:

```
ArrayList tempList2 = new ArrayList();
tempList2 = getXYZ(tempList1, tempList2);

//method getXYZ
getXYZ(ArrayList tempList1, ArrayList tempList2) {

  //does some logic and adds objects into tempList2

  return tempList2;
}
```

The code will get executed but it seems by passing tempList2 to the getXYZ method argument, it is doing object recycling.

My question is, Is recycling the tempList2 arraylist object correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, Is recycling the tempList2 arraylist object correct?

I don't quite know what you mean by "recycling".  This doesn't appear to be a case where the application is recycling objects in an attempt to avoid allocating new objects.  (That is the normal meaning of "recycling" in Java.)

If `getXYZ` is called multiple times with the same `tempList2` object, then this is simply a way of aggregating stuff into a single list.  The fact that `getXYZ` returns an `ArrayList` leaves open the possibility that the method implementation may be changed to return a different `ArrayList` instance.  That's not a problem *per se*, but it might be if the caller doesn't assign the result of the call appropriately.

If `getXYZ` is only called once for any given `tempList2` object, then this looks a bit strange.

In summary, this code looks a bit fishy, and is fragile if someone changes the implementation of `getXYZ`.  However, it is not down-right wrong, and there may be some good reason (or historical reason) for doing things this way that is not apparent in the small chunks of code you included in the question.

**EDIT** - in response to this comment (inlined to make it readable)

> Actually, the reason for the above code is, I wanted to avoid creating two arraylist objects. For ex: the conventional method would be

```
ArrayList tempList2 = new ArrayList(); 
tempList2 = getXYZ(tempList1);

//method getXYZ 
getXYZ(ArrayList tempList1) { 
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
    //INSTANTIATED ONLY ONCE 
    //does some logic and adds objects into tempList 
    return tempList; 
}
```

---

The *real* conventional way of doing this would be:

```
ArrayList tempList2 = getXYZ(tempList1);
```

or

```
ArrayList tempList2;
// some intermediate lines
tempList2 = getXYZ(tempList1);
```

Neither of these require creating the unnecessary `ArrayList` instance of your approach, and neither require passing 2 `ArrayList` instances into the `getXYZ` method.

Comment: Actually, the reason for the above code is, I wanted to avoid creating two arraylist objects. For ex: the conventional method would be
    ArrayList tempList2 = new ArrayList();
    tempList2 = getXYZ(tempList1);
    //method getXYZ
    getXYZ(ArrayList tempList1) {
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();//INSTANTIATED ONLY ONCE
      //does some logic and adds objects into tempList
      return tempList;
    }

Answer (score 3):

There's really no such concept as "object recycling" here. Nothing's being garbage collected, if that's what you're interested in... at least, not if there are no lines like this:

```
tempList2 = new ArrayList();
```

within `getXYZ()`.

The reference to the `ArrayList` is passed into the method and then returned. That's all. It's just a reference - it's not the object itself.

Now you could say it's slightly odd for the method to return the `ArrayList` reference which was passed into it... usually that's used for fluent interfaces, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the value of the `tempList2` reference.  The object itself isn't copied.  So when the passed-in `tempList2` is modified, the caller sees the changes.  This is also called [call-by-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

So there's nothing wrong, once you understand what's going on.

Comment: I'd like to add that this sort of behaviour is usually frowned upon in Java code, this is basically relying on side effect to make things work. That doesn't make this wrong but I'd still avoid doing anything like this.

Comment: It depends.  I would avoid it in a public API, but internally it could be convenient.